# Integral Representation of $\frac{\mathrm{sign}(x)}{|x|^{s}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104248307), on page 433 (4.12), the authors used an integral formula of the function $\frac{\mathrm{sign}(x)}{|x|^{s}}$, which is

$$|x|^{-s}\mathrm{sign}(x)=\frac{2}{\Gamma(\frac{s+1}{2})}\int_{0}^{\infty}dyy^{s}xe^{-x^{2}y^{2}}$$

for any real non-zero $x$.

This integral seems very unexptected. Can anybody tell me how one knows that the function can be expressed in the above integral? Is there any motivation behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Laplace transform. Roughly, powers of $y$ transform to powers of $x^{-1}$ because $x,y$ have opposite dimension (as seen from the $x^2y^2$ term in the exponential). Changing variable $u=y^2$ would tidy it up, and then it would be essentially the definition of the Gamma function, which is the Laplace transform of $x^a$.

Answer (score 1):

After a change of variables $y = \sqrt{s}/|x|$, it becomes the integral formula for the Gamma function.